# Parse - for OSx Swift

Tags: macos, swift, parse-platform

I'm unable to integrate parse in my OSx project( in SWIFT). I had already added the:

- CFNetwork.framework
- CoreGraphics.framework
- CoreLocation.framework
- libsqlite3.dylib
- libz.dylib
- QuartzCore.framework
- Security.framework
- SystemConfiguration.framework
- Bolts.framework
- ParseOSx.framework

and I have added an Objective-C file and bridged it and imported `#import<ParseOSx/Parse.h>`  in .h file, still i'm getting error that unresolved use of parse identifier when i'm setting up the application-Id and client key.

Answer (score 1):

just change import in your bridge with this:

```
#import <ParseOSX/ParseOSX.h>
```